# Make JSON Object in python

Tags: python, json

I want make JSON Object in python like this :

```
{
"to":["admin"],
"content":{
           "message":"everything",
           "command":0,
           "date":["tag1",...,"tagn"]
           },
"time":"YYYYMMDDhhmmss"
}
```

This is my code in python :

```
import json

cont = [{"message":"everything","command":0,"data":["tag1","tag2"]}]
json_content = json.dumps(cont,sort_keys=False,indent=2)
print json_content

data = [{"to":("admin"),"content":json_content, "time":"YYYYMMDDhhmmss"}]
json_obj = json.dumps(data,sort_keys=False, indent =2)

print json_obj
```

But I get the result like this :

```
[
  {
    "content": "[\n  {\n    \"data\": [\n      \"tag1\", \n      \"tag2\"\n    ], \n    \"message\": \"everything\", \n    \"command\": 0\n  }\n]", 
    "to": "admin", 
    "time": "YYYYMMDDhhmmss"
  }
]
```

Could someone please help me? Thankyou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically build a JSON object with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110383/how-to-dynamically-build-a-json-object-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Nested `json` content

`json_content` is a `json` string representation returned by the first call to `json.dumps()`, this is why you get a string version of the content in the second call to `json.dumps()`.  You need to call `json.dumps()` once on the whole python object after you place the original content, `cont`, directly into `data`.

```
import json

cont = [{
    "message": "everything",
    "command": 0,
    "data"   : ["tag1", "tag2"]
}]

data = [{
    "to"      : ("admin"), 
    "content" : cont, 
    "time"    : "YYYYMMDDhhmmss"
}]
json_obj = json.dumps(data,sort_keys=False, indent =2)

print json_obj
```

---

```
[
  {
    "content": [
      {
        "data": [
          "tag1", 
          "tag2"
        ], 
        "message": "everything", 
        "command": 0
      }
    ], 
    "to": "admin", 
    "time": "YYYYMMDDhhmmss"
  }
]
```