# How do I return dictionary value as variable within the class

Tags: python

I have the following class that returns the dictionary given the `kwargs` as an input.

```
class Emp_Constant:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

However, in some instances, I would like to pass the dictionary as an input to this class and access the key values as variables.

For example, if my dictionary is `{'name': 'Tome', 'age':'26'}`, then 
I would like to access 'Tom' as below:

```
set = {'name': 'Tom', 'age':'26'}
a = Emp_Constant(set)
first_emp = a.NAME (where NAME is a variable that holds value of key 'name')
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51315029/3702377) is another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use the "double-splat" operator to unpack the dictionary as key-word arguments, and then use `getattr`:

```
In [30]: class Emp_Constant:
    ...:     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    ...:         for key, value in kwargs.items():
    ...:             setattr(self, key, value)
    ...:

In [31]: data = {'name': 'Tom', 'age':'26'}
    ...: a = Emp_Constant(**data)
    ...:
    ...: NAME = 'name'
    ...:
    ...:

In [32]: getattr(a, NAME)
Out[32]: 'Tom'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a dict unpacking

```
a = Emp_Constant(**set)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `obj_dict = Emp_Constant(**set)`

---

### Alternative way, using the [EasyDict](https://github.com/makinacorpus/easydict) library:

```
from easydict import EasyDict as edict

set = {'name': 'Tom', 'age':'26'}
obj_dict = edict(set)

print(obj_dict.name)
```

[Out]:

```
'Tom'
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want the class to take in name and age either way?

How about:

```
class Emp_Constant:
def __init__(self, useADict=None, **kwargs):
    if useADict:
        self.name = useADict.name
        self.age = useADict.age
    else:
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your passing the dictionary as the first parameter, instead of using **- in your example, you should have done:

```
set = {'name': 'x', 'age': 10}
a = Emp_Constant(**set)
```

Then you can access `a.name`