# create a json file from a list in python

Tags: python, json

I have this code that allows me to create a JSON file from a list, creates the list, checks that the elements don't repeat, and then creates the JSON file.

```
import json

res = []
seen = set()

def add_entry(res, id, tf1, tf2, tf3):

    # check if in seen set
    if (id, tf1, tf2, tf3) in seen:
        return res

    # add to seen set
    seen.add(tuple([id, tf1, tf2, tf3]))

    # append to results list
    res.append({'metrica': id, 'ft1': tf1, 'tf2': tf2, 'tf3': tf3})

    return res

args = ['ext:tech.DB2', '40,023', '168,481', '15,55']
res = add_entry(res, *args)

args = ['ext:bim.DB2', '25,02', '18,81', '5,35']
res = add_entry(res, *args)

def write_to_json(lst, fn):
    with open(fn, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for item in lst:
            x = json.dumps(item, indent=4)
            file.write(x + '\n')

#export to JSON
write_to_json(res, 'elements.json')
```

Only the JSON file is not a real JSON file:

```
{
    "metrica": "ext:bim.DB2",
    "ft1": "40,023",
    "tf2": "168,481",
    "tf3": "15,55"
}
{
    "metrica": "ext:bim.DB2",
    "ft1": "25,02",
    "tf2": "18,81",
    "tf3": "5,35"
}
```

How can I make it like this:

```
{"data":[{
    "metrica": "ext:bim.DB2",
    "ft1": "40,023",
    "tf2": "168,481",
    "tf3": "15,55"
},
{
    "metrica": "ext:bim.DB2",
    "ft1": "25,02",
    "tf2": "18,81",
    "tf3": "5,35"
}]}
```

the json file I generate it in the code and then dynamically I need to pass it to another function, even if I wanted to, I could not change the values manually, also because I would have more than 900 elements to change, how can I do it dynamically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically build a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110383/how-to-dynamically-build-a-json-object) You already have the list, for your expected output `json.dump({"data": lst}, file, indent=4)` should ideally be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of saving each element of list separately, save the entire list.

```
def write_to_json(lst, fn):
    out = {}
    out["data"] = lst
    with open(fn, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        x = json.dumps(out, indent=4)
        file.write(x + '\n')
```

To simplify further,

```
x = json.dumps(out, indent=4)
file.write(x + '\n')
```

is more or less the same as `json.dump(out, file, indent=4)` (`dump` writes directly to file, `dumps` returns a string - same is true for analogous `load` and `loads` methods that read from file or parse a string). We can then get rid of explicit `out` object and just create it inside the dump function. That gives us much cleaner version that Abdul suggested in comment.

```
def write_to_json(lst, fn):
    with open(fn, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        json.dump({'data': lst}, file, indent=4)
```

Comment: (Also, don't use `'a'`. Use `'w'` to ensure a valid file each time)

Comment: @quamrana Fair, just copied what was in OPs original code

Comment: Yes, I realised that. Anyway +1 for a working answer.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, it is perfectly what i needed